# "Cannot Find Symbol" in Sub Class Java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a sub class named "**public class Once**" and am getting the error "**Cannot Find Symbol**" on the lines "**return date**;" and "**return descript**;".  I know its probably something really stupid I am missing, but any help would be great.

Here is my code!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Once
{
public Once(String dateIn, String descripIn)
{
  String date = dateIn;
  String descrip = descripIn;
}

public String getDate()
{
  return date;
}

public String getDescrip()
{
  return descrip;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined date and descrip local in constructor.

It should be

```
public class Once{
    String date;
    String descrip;

    public Once(String dateIn, String descripIn)
    {
      date = dateIn;
      descrip = descripIn;
    }
    // other methods
}
```

Comment: I just inputted that and returned "date" and "descript" and am now getting the error "class, interface, or enum expected"

Answer (score 1):

You do not have those set as [fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).  A field defines a specific attribute about an object.

What you'll want to do is set them up as such:

```
public class Once {

    private String date;
    private String descrip;

    //initialize in constructor
    public Once(String dateIn, String descripIn) {
        date = dateIn;
        descrip = descripIn;
    }
    //Add getters and setters.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Those variables are only in the scope of the Once() method. You need to declare them inside the class scope:

```
public class Once
{
    String date, descrip;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Right now they are being defined in a *constructor*, not a method.

Answer (score 0):

Date and descrip need to be defined at the class level not as local variables.